# A more robust WriteFile

Tags: c++, winapi, file-io, nas

Our problem:
We are capturing video and writing the data to a FileSystem, usually a NAS device. So we have sequential data to be written, and this code will be writing to multiple files on the same NAS - for 99% of the time it works, however occasionally this function will just hang.

I have this function that writes data to a file.

```
STDMETHODIMP FileWriter::Receive(LONG lStreamId, IStreamPacket* pPacket)
{
    CMutexAutoLock lock(&m_csAccessControl);

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    // AddRef the packet to prevent loss
    pPacket->AddRef();

    if (m_hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE && pPacket) {
        DWORD written = 0;
        BYTE* pData = NULL;
        LONG lLen = 0;
        pPacket->get_Pointer(&pData);
        pPacket->get_ActualDataLength(&lLen);
        if (pData && lLen) {
            WriteFile(m_hFile, pData, lLen, &written, NULL);
            m_llPosition += written;
            if (m_llPosition > m_llLength) {
                m_llLength = m_llPosition;
            }
        }
        m_xiPosition = (LONG)m_llPosition;
        m_xiLength = (LONG)m_llLength;
        m_xiLengthInMB = (LONG)(m_llLength/1024/1024);
    }

    // Release packet
    pPacket->Release();

    return hr;
}
```

Now, I cannot test this code easily, as it is used internally to a framework I am using. I do however have this code handy.

I have read online that the WriteFile() function *can* freeze the application, and this happens to us when the target file system is a NAS, but only very occasionally. When writing to the local HDD, this is never an issue. Unfortunately we require a very robust solution that we can write to a NAS without issue.

How could I modify this code so that the WriteFile() function always completes? I have read about using Overlapped IO, but I am not sure how I would go about this and if this is suitable.

Comment: Overlapped I/O is asynchronous, alternatively move your I/O to a non-UI thread. A lot of NAS devices seem particularly buggy and very sensitive to buffer size, so play around with the amount of data you're trying to write in one go.

Comment: @JonathanPotter thanks, I will try to play around with buffer sizes. I have a feeling this is already done on a non-UI thread. In the meantime, how difficult is it to implement Overlapped IO?

Comment: Just don't go there, that only adds more bugs.  Fix your hardware, network card, driver and NAS are on your chop list.  Anti-malware and firewall if you use them.  This kind of hardware is normally dirt-cheap, be sure to spend the money on something decent.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, although we already spend quite a bit on our hardware. We never buy consumer grade hardware, its always industrial gear. Appreciate the comment on using Overlapped IO though - that's kind of my last resort

Comment: How long a freeze are we talking about?

Comment: I think it causes a follow on effect, as the writing process interrupts the capturing process, so effectively a hard restart of the application is required.